# Adding footer on every page generated using Visual Force

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, css

Hello I have the below VF page which I use to generate a letter. I am not using "visualforce page that is rendered as PDF". I searched about "visualforce page that is rendered as PDF" but when I tried that out in my page it did not work.

```
<apex:page standardController="P__c" showHeader="false" extensions="Bclass">
<apex:form >
<apex:image url="{!imageURL}" style="width:720px" ></apex:image>

 <apex:panelGrid columns="2" width="720px">

       <apex:panelGrid columns="1" width="95%">        
            <span style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size:16px;"><b>DOB Job Number:</b> {!P__c.DOB__c}</span><br/>   
space:nowrap;"><b>Premises:</b> {!P__c.address__c}</span>
       </apex:panelGrid>


</apex:panelGrid>  
<br></br> 

<div id="container2" style="width:720px">
 <apex:repeat value="{!objlist}" var="d">
    <tr>
    <td><apex:outputText value="{!d}" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size:16px;" /></td><br></br>
    </tr>
 </apex:repeat>
</div>
<!-- Want to add this image footer in all pages -->
<apex:image url="{!image_footer_URL}" style="width:720px" ></apex:image>
<!-- Want to add this image footer in all pages -->

<apex:commandButton action="{!Savecopy}" disabled="false" value="Save"/>

</apex:form>


</apex:page>
```

Some of the online answers assumes that `<apex:page renderAs="pdf"` is used in the VF page, but in my case I do not use this tag if you have noticed. I use the below code in my apex controller class to render a pdf version:

```
  public PageReference Savecopy(){
      PageReference p = Page.RSheet;
      blob b = ApexPages.currentPage().getContentAsPDF ();

      Attachment a = new Attachment();
      a.body = b;
      a.name = 'Sheet '+currentdate+'.pdf';
      a.parentid = pID;

      insert a;

      PageReference pref = new PageReference('/'+pID);
      return pref;
   }
```

How can I make this move to footer area. I want to make this footer visible in all the pages that are generated.

The answers at at this link- https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003705&language=en_US does not fit in with my case. I need to do a work around for this, Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a visualforce component that is the footer, then build a page that will be your template and add the footer in there.

**Component (VF Component)**

```
<apex:component>
   Your VF Footer markup
</apex:component>
```

**Template (VF Page)**

```
<apex:page>
    Header and body go first
    <apex:insert name="footer">
        <c:FooterComponentName>
    </apex:insert>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I have an image variable which I use in footer. I get this image from a custom controller class. How can I include at in VF component?

Comment: Either a) use a controller for your component or b) pass the value to your component using apex:attribute.

Comment: Can you show me a sample code how to do it?

Comment: Components supports only standard controller and my logic is in extension

Comment: Tried this- "<apex:component standardController="P__c" extensions="Bexten">" But I get an Error: Unsupported attribute standardcontroller in <apex:component> in check at line 1 column 54

Comment: Last I checked apex:insert counted as an extra page view for force.com sites. If you use sites this approach might not be the best. No issue with using it other places that I know of though.

Answer (score 2):

follow this link.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003705&language=en_US

nice example for Adding page header/footer into a VisualForce page

If you are not using pdf then you may want to use `apex:define` and `apex:composition`

Here the examples https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_define.htm

http://www.infallibletechie.com/2013/04/apexinsert-apexcomposition-apexdefine.html

This a Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ratan_Paul/2vxvhzce/  for html fixed header and footer

Here is example with two VF pages and common controller

https://gist.github.com/RatanPaul/2c1e04b0f7846ca333bc

Comment: Hello , But I do not use <apex:page renderAs="pdf">, Please see my edits on top.

Comment: @Rdvsm. updated ans plz check. May this will help you

Comment: Hi, I tried this and made a difference, however as I generate the content of the body dynamically on the page, the footer does not go at the bottom of all the pages and appears in the middle when the content in the body is less. I use <br></br> in "template" file to move the footer to the bottom for a page. Can I make any change(may be add css style?) to keep the footer always at the bottom of the page?

Comment: I think you need like this.. plz check Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ratan_Paul/2vxvhzce/   Also update my ans plz check

Comment: Thanks, the footer works when I preview my VF page , however when I view the generated pdf, the content of the footer moves up and does not appear as expected. Any changes to be made to reflect in pdf too? Thanks

Comment: if you want for pdf then this may not work you need to follow this ex https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003705&language=en_US

Comment: Thanks, but the reason I do not use renderAs=pdf is I want to be able to save this VF page as pdf in notes & attachment section. I have a custom link which leads to the VF page, which has a save option to save it in attachment section as pdf. So i am unable to use the link you provided. Any other work around for this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31956/discussion-between-ratan-and-rdvsm).

Comment: you can create 2 vf page and use same controller. 1 vf page for renderAs pdf and another one simple vf page. use specific css https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003705&language=en_US and http://jsfiddle.net/Ratan_Paul/2vxvhzce/

Comment: @Rdvsm check this out https://gist.github.com/RatanPaul/2c1e04b0f7846ca333bc

Comment: Hi , thanks for sending this, but when I tried to replace the code with mine , the footer still moves up and does not appear at the botto. Here is my code: [link]https://gist.github.com/vijay24805/911986a750e5b3314a78

Comment: hey @Rdvsm use `applyBodyTag="false"` then it will work

Comment: Hi, when I use this on my page, the footer goes at the bottom but the body content is on top of the page and styling looks disrupted.

Comment: if it is plz go with `applyBodyTag="false"` and inside body try to avoid using `apex:panelGrid ` or VF tags. maximum try to use html tags and css